# Cannot install OpenOnload on AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, openonload

I am trying to install OpenOnload on an AWS server running Ubuntu server 18.04.3. I downloaded the DEB release package from version 7.1.0.265 (the latest) from here: https://support.solarflare.com/index.php/component/cognidox/?view=categories&id=361

and then extract out of it just the folder \onload_7.1.0.265-debiansource.tgz\onload_7.1.0.265.orig.tar.gz and untar that. Then I can run

```
$ ./scripts/onload_install
```

as per the instructions in the README file. On Ubuntu 20 on my local machine this all worked and installed OpenOnload fine but on an AWS server instance this error is thrown:

```
onload_install: Building Onload.
Build tree made for linux as x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws
make: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws'
# Build both autocompat.h files: linux_net and linux_affinity.
make -C driver/linux_net
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net'
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1057-aws CC="cc" M=$(pwd)
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1057-aws'
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/src/driver/linux_net/Makefile:61: SFE4001/Falcon is no longer supported
  CHK     /home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/autocompat.h
  UPD     /home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/autocompat.h
  CHK     /home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/config.h
  UPD     /home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/config.h
  CC [M]  /home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.o
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.c: In function ‘efx_init_struct’:
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.c:5225:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘efx_mtd_free’; did you mean ‘efx_mtd_probe’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  efx_mtd_free(efx);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  efx_mtd_probe
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.c:5224:1: warning: label ‘fail’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
 fail:
 ^~~~
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.c: In function ‘efx_fini_struct’:
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.c:5247:9: error: ‘struct efx_nic’ has no member named ‘mtd_struct’
  if (efx->mtd_struct) {
         ^~
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.c:5248:6: error: ‘struct efx_nic’ has no member named ‘mtd_struct’
   efx->mtd_struct->efx = NULL;
      ^~
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.c:5249:6: error: ‘struct efx_nic’ has no member named ‘mtd_struct’
   efx->mtd_struct = NULL;
      ^~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net/efx.o] Error 1
Makefile:1580: recipe for target '_module_/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-1057-aws'
/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/src/driver/linux_net/Makefile:300: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws/driver/linux_net'
../../src/mmake.mk:57: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/onload-7.1.0.265/build/x86_64_linux-4.15.0-1057-aws'
onload_build: ERROR: Failed to build driver components.
onload_install: ERROR: Build failed.  Not installing.
```

Could this be due to incompatibility with some specific features on AWS? I checked the version compatibility for the downloaded source and it says compatible with Ubuntu server 18.04. Any ideas on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Onload-7.0.0.176` compiles without any issues. Seems new version has some compilation bugs. If you can, maybe you could use that version?

Comment: Cheers, what did you use to compile it - $ sudo ./scripts/onload_install ? Or something else? And was it on an AWS instance?

Comment: Yes, `sudo ./scripts/onload_install` on AWS. Had to install `build-essential` package first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The **solution** was to use `Onload-7.0.0.176` instead of `Onload-7.1.0.265`.

Seems version `Onload-7.1.0.265` has some compilation bugs on Ubuntu 18.04.